# df.rename(columns) takes too long compared to df.columns.to_series().replace({}). WHY?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset with 30 columns and 132427 rows and I have to rename all of the columns. I have used **df.rename({})** function before but now it takes too long and eats up my memory but when I use **df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace({})** it does the job in a matter of a second. I would like to know the reason behind this behaviour so I can choose better next time.

Comment: `df.rename` copies the Dataframe unless you specify `inplace=True`, assigning to columns is in-place.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data with your code, so we can see where the performance bottleneck is